# Is there an efficient alternative (in Kotlin) to this code format: <functionReturningAList>().size?

Tags: list, kotlin, return, size

If the function will execute first before getting the size, then I think that it will be inefficient because you're just getting the size of the returning list, the number of elements of which is immutable anyways (I mean list doesn't allow element addition, so the size of the returning list is supposed to be constant).

For context, I want to hold a reference to the size of the returned list, as a qualification in a later if condition, such that if I ever programmatically change the number of list elements, I don't need to also manually change the 'qualified' size, it as a constant.

I'm worried that if I apply the above format to codes, it will become a bad practice, a concise code sacrificing performance.

For example:

```
class Sampler {
        // notice this is var
        var sampleList = initializeList()
        
        // ...

        companion object {
            private fun initializeList(): List<Int> =
                listOf(
                    // these functions may return differently later
                    anObject.getNumber(1),
                    anotherObject.getInt(2),
                    yetAnotherObject.getInteger(3)
                    // can be programmatically added later
                )

            fun sampleMethod(numberToBeCompared) {
                // I don't want to do this: numberToBeCompared == QUALIFIED_LIST_CONSTANT
                if (numberToBeCompared == initializeList().size)
                    println("do something")

                // ...

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "the number of elements of which is immutable anyways"? The function can decide to return a list of any size though. You can't know the size of the list without executing the function.

Comment: e.g. The function could return `List(size = someTimeConsumingFunctionGivesANumber()) { 0 }`. It could also return a `MutableList`, since `MutableList` inherits `List`. In that case the size certainly is not "immutable", is it?

Comment: @Sweeper 'the number of elements of <"...the returning list"> is immutable anyways'.
If you examine the example I provided, which is a translated code of what I'm currently facing, the elements are definite without actually executing them.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you are trying to do after re-reading your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing a `List<() -> Int>`? That is, turn each of the expressions for the elements in the list to a "thunk", that when invoked, returns the element:

```
val listOfThunks =
    listOf(
        { anObject.getNumber(1) },
        { anotherObject.getInt(2) },
        { yetAnotherObject.getInteger(3) }
        // can be programmatically added later
    )
```

Since this is just a bunch of lambda expressions, it can be evaluated very quickly.

Then `initializeList` can be implemented as mapping each element to its invoked result:

```
private fun initializeList(): List<Int> = listOfThunks.map { it() }
```

To get the size, simply get `listOfThunks.size`, which does not invoke any of the lambdas, nor `initializeList`.